# Maven create incremental child project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, inheritance, structure

- I have webapp project A with its own lifecycle with war packaging.
- Now I want to create another Project B (war) that depends on Project A. Also in project B I want to overwrite some resources(files replacement).
- War Packaging of B should includes jar from Project A, jar from project B and merged resource in classes folder.

What I tried and failed.

- If I keep parent packaging as war then I can not use as `parent` in child pom.
- I have changed parent packaging as pom but in eclipse I can not able to resolve parent classes in child project.
- I add dependency as war in child then again I can not resolve parent classes in child.

I was able to build this with some custom ant task but I also want to run directly from eclipse simply by adding in server and it does not seems standard way and takes time in development as I need to always compile and run `tomcat7:run-war` task.

How can I structure this to achieve my goals?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use A as a parent project.  Instead having A (type WAR) as a  normal dependency to B (also a WAR project) means that the final war artifact for B consists of the files in the A artifact *overlaid* with the resources provided by the B source tree.  EDIT:  Unfortunately this doesn't make Java classes in A visible to B.  For this to work you must split A in a jar and a war artifact and depend on both.

Note that <strike>B</strike> A cannot contain Java sources then.  They need to come from an artifact dependency.

In other words, rearrange so A is a normal dependency to B.

Comment: Keep the parent as close to empty as possible.

Comment: i have tried this, but in project B it can not resolve classes from A [ B(war) depends A(war)], compilation failed

Comment: Ah, that is true.  You must move the code from A into a separate project for this to work.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Shouldn't transitive dependencies be normally reachable, as long they've been properly declared and POM published, regardless of WAR packaging of A?